# "IndexError: list index out of range" retrieving image and texts

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

when retrieving image and texts from sqlite3 database using tkinter in Python I'm getting an error even though there are 3 objects in the database (2 texts and 1 blob).

Code:

```
def retrieve():
    global  ntr, img, mylabel

    conn = sqlite3.connect('info.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM students WHERE id_name like ? ",(ntr.get(),))
    records = c.fetchmany()
    
    first1 = records[0]
    second2 = records[1]
    third = records[2]

    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(third))
    img = img.resize((80, 80))
    img =ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    mylabel = Label(root, image=img, width=80, height=80)
    mylabel.grid()

    mylabel2 = Label(root, text =first1)
    mylabel2.grid()

    mylabel3 =Label(root, text= second2)
    mylabel3.grid()
```

Error:

> second2 = records[1] IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Have you tried `print(records)` to see what you're actually getting?

Comment: If your database table has 3 rows and you want all of them, remove the `WHERE` clause from your query.

Comment: what to use instead of WERE?

Comment: why not run the loop for each record? This question is for debugging

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do a wildcard character search, you need to put the wildcard in single quotes:

```
"SELECT * FROM students WHERE id_name like ? "
```

becomes

```
"SELECT * FROM students WHERE id_name like '?' "
```

But, as jordanm already mentioned, this is kind of a pointless endeavor as it looks you are are trying to get everything from the table. If you are trying to get everything, remove the where clause all together:

```
"SELECT * FROM students"
```

Comment: I tried:
`c.execute("SELECT * FROM students ",(ntr.get(),))`

and
`"c.execute(SELECT * FROM students WHERE id_name like '?',(ntr.get(),)) "`

error

`c.execute("SELECT * FROM students WHERE id_name like '?' ",(ntr.get(),))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.`

Comment: Try removing the ntr.get() from the c.execute.